# Web Server using wrong protocol to connect to SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, tcp, udp

I have two web servers that each run an identical ASP application. These web servers connect to the same SQL server. One of the servers is running the application fine, but the other is throwing the following error:

A network-related or instance-specific error occurred while establishing a connection to SQL Server. The server was not found or was not accessible. Verify that the instance name is correct and that SQL Server is configured to allow remote connections. (provider: SQL Network Interfaces, error: 28 - Server doesn't support requested protocol)

I did a wireshark capture on both of traffic in between the web server and the sql server. On the working server, the traffic is using TCP. On the nonworking server, I see alot of UDP traffic, which SQL server doesn't support (makes sense given the error message). Where is the protocol used determined? The applications on each server are identical, so it can't be an application level config issue. I am not a network guy so I am at a loss

Thanks,

Joseph

Comment: You cannot use an sql server with udp packages, at least it does not make sense. Are those packages _really_ from the sql client? Or is it more some networking discovery service trying to find out the network topology? This would hint on deeper network problems on that system.

Comment: They are originating from the web client, not the sql client. Not sure why this server is trying to communicate with this protocol

Comment: Hu? What is the "web client" in this? A browser? A browser certainly does not directly connect to a sql server, at least this does not make sense at all...

Answer (score 0):

You can set the "network protocol" in the connection string.

It's worth a try.

Connect via an IP address

```
Data Source=190.190.200.100,1433;Network Library=DBMSSOCN;
```

That connection string is not complete, I'm showing the relevant portions.

That sample comes from

http://www.connectionstrings.com/sql-server-2008

This article is old, but will explain the Network Library options.

http://support.microsoft.com/kb/238949

The 2 most common (in my experience) are:

```
dbnmpntw - Win32 Named Pipes
dbmssocn - Win32 Winsock TCP/IP
```

EDIT

The other trick is to install PortQryUI, and place this small utility on the "client" machine.......and "poke" the Sql Server, and make sure you get the same results.

http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=24009

This will help identify any firewall issues...OUTSIDE of using sql server clients.

Comment: I actually was able to connect to the database using the ODBC manager

Comment: Ok...ODBC is a good "poor man's check".  So I'd try to specify the Network Library explicitly (seen above)......because if you don't, it will use some defaults...that are hidden in the registry......IIRC.  Like I said, try the "most specific connection string" you can......which means... IP address, port# and the network library...........plus the other "credentials".

Comment: What credentials are you using?  (Aka, what "identity" are you using to connect to the database?)